# PHP and Javascript - DIVs won't hide

Tags: php, javascript, css

I'm trying to make it so when user goes to dashboard.php?option=home, they are presented with only support_ticket_div, while when they go to dashboard.php?option=ucp, they are presented only with control_panel_div. For some reason, the DIVs won't hide when I click on the buttons with those links from above. Instead, both of the DIVs show, one under another. This is my PHP code that is placed before the DIVs:

```
<?php 
  if($_GET['option'] == 'home') { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">setcontent(1);</script> <?
  }
  if($_GET['option'] == 'ucp') { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">setcontent(2);</script> <?
  } 
?>
```

This is my setcontent() javascript function located in the  tags in the head section

```
function setcontent(id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById('control_panel_div').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('support_ticket_div').style.display = 'inline';
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById('support_ticket_div').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('control_panel_div').style.display = 'inline';
            break;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks...

Comment: "This is my PHP code that is placed before the DIVs" Try placing that after the divs...

Comment: Also, try putting alert(id); in the function to be sure the code is executing and the id is what you think it is.

Comment: try to add a default case in your switch to see if your id is correct

Comment: @ j08691 Thanks mate, I don't understand how I forgot about that *facepalm*

Comment: make sure your `div Ids` are loaded in DOM when are selected otherwise  setcontent will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to execute your function before the elements exist in the DOM.

"This is my PHP code that is placed before the DIVs" Try placing that after the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 case 1: ...
        alert("case 1");
        break;

 default:
        document.getElementById('control_panel_div').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('support_ticket_div').style.display = 'none';
        break;
```

if you always go to the default section, try to parsint() your id